# Running "net" commands with /domain flag outside of the domain

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, active-directory, runas

As a part of my work I sometimes connect to a network with an AD environment/Domain, and receive domain user credentials. However, my machine is not a part of the domain. So when I try to query the domain (inside a runas /netonly) window, I get this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net accounts /do
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain WORKGROUP.

System error 1355 has occurred.

The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
```

However, if I run the same command from a  computer inside that domain I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net accounts /do
Force user logoff how long after time expires?:       Never
Minimum password age (days):                          0
Maximum password age (days):                          42
Minimum password length:                              0
Length of password history maintained:                None
Lockout threshold:                                    Never
Lockout duration (minutes):                           30
Lockout observation window (minutes):                 30
Computer role:                                        domain.local
The command completed successfully.
```

Again, this is inside a runas /netonly window titled "cmd/exe (running as domain.loca\username)".
The same happens for all similar commands such as "net user username /domain"

Is there any way to query these "net" commands from a computer outside the domain (whilst having a domain user of course)?

As additional note, some external tools (like the Windows Resource Kit or even PingCastle) work perfectly with runas / netonly.

Comment: It would help if you include the command you're using to start the instance of Command Prompt from which you're running these commands. That might make your question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Microsoft support article [Net Commands On Windows Operating Systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/556003), the NET command's `/domain` switch performs the requested operation on a domain controller of the current domain.

For a machine not joined to a Active Directory domain, the "current domain" is the computer's workgroup. But workgroups don't have domain controllers which is why your NET command is failing:

> The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain *WORKGROUP*.
>
> System error 1355 has occurred.
>
> *The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted*.

*(emphasis mine)*

There's no way around this. The `/domain` switch is hard coded to read the local machine's domain membership to determine where to look for a domain controller. It has nothing to do with the credentials you use when executing the command, so running it with a domain user's credentials won't make a difference.

Your best option is to execute these commands from a machine that is a member of the domain you wish to query.

Comment: Thanks for the edits in the other post, BTW _Brick_ it was really _brick_. `:-)`

Comment: Oops! I was editing on my mobile and missed that!